# Check if y-axis begins at zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to determine if a plot generated by `ggplot` begins at zero.

I am generating a couple hundred reports that each have thirty or more charts in them. I am content with `ggplot`'s defaults for when a plot starts at zero and when it doesn't, but I want to add a caption that draws the reader's attention to this fact.

Something like:

```
labs(caption = ifelse(XXXXX, "Note: y-axis does not begin at zero", ""))
```

But I have no clue what my test should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=0:9), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
yrange <- ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
if(yrange[1] <= 0) g <- g + labs(caption = "Note: y-axis does not begin at zero")
plot(g)
```